# Does $1 \in P$ where $P$ is a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

My guess is that if that condition holds then probably $P=R$ where $R$ is the ring .Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, that is true. And that holds for ANY ideal

Comment: Is this the same reason as to why we do not consider 1 as a prime number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $1\in P$ then for each $x\in R$ we have $x=x1\in P$. So yes, if any ideal contains the identity then it is the whole ring.